# Boost Python Converter for Custom Bool Type

Tags: boost-python

I have a custom type that is basically a C++ boolean with extra functions. I need to access my C++ libraries via Python and the framework is based on Boost.

Currently I have to use ints instead of bools, because the backend can convert from int to my custom type just fine. I need to be able to convert from python's bool to my custom bool when necessary and vice versa.

Here is some code that mimicks what I have done so far:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class CustomBool
{
public:
    CustomBool(bool b) : is_set(b) {}
    operator bool() const { return is_set; };
private:
    bool is_set{false};
};

struct Example
{
    CustomBool get_CustomBool(bool x)
    {
        return CustomBool(x);
    }
    bool convert_custom(bool x)
    {
        return bool(CustomBool(x));
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bptest)
{

    implicitly_convertible<CustomBool, bool>();
    implicitly_convertible<bool, CustomBool>();
    
    Py_Initialize();

    class_<Example>("Example")
        .def("convert_custom", &Example::convert_custom)
        .def("get_CustomBool", &Example::get_CustomBool);
}
```

When I use it in Python I get the following:

```py
>>> from bptest import Example
>>> ex = Example()
>>> ex.get_CustomBool(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: CustomBool
```

I have found some string conversion examples, but I couldn't transfer their solutions to my (simpler?) problem.

The docs (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/to_from_python_type_conversion.html) are also not helpful to me, but maybe for anyone else?

Comment: You need to include some converter structures that will take care of the conversion between CustomBool and pythons bool type. These custom type conversion mechanisms then need to be added to the registry using the 'converter::registry::push_back' function.